# About virtual functions

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    int x;
    A(int i = 0): x(i) {}
    A minus(){
        return 1 - x;
    }
    virtual void print(){
        cout << x << "\n";
        cout << "Base print\n";
    }
};

class B: public A{
    int y;
public:
    B(int i = 0) {x = i;}
    void print(){
    cout << x << "\n";
    cout << "Derived print!\n";
    }
   };

int main(){
    A* p1 = new B(18);
    *p1 = p1->minus();
    p1->print();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
-17
Derived print!
```

I know where `-17` comes from. It does upcasting and  `A* p1 = new B(18)` and makes `p1` point to a derived object with x value of 18. `*p1 = p1->minus` make the object that `p1` points to be an `A(-17) /// cause 1 -18 = -17`. My question is, where does the second line come from ? If p1 points to an `A` object after the `*p1 = p1->minus()`, why does `p1->print()` not print `"Base print"` ?

Comment: Assigning a `A` to a `B` doesn't change the dynamic type of the `B` to `A`. Once you `new B` it is impossible to change the type of that object by any means.

Comment: `p1` still points to a `B`, `*p = someA;` just assigns the `A`'s part.

Comment: Assigning a base object to a derived object can lead to [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing), beware.

Comment: @alexMcKenzie You explicitly called the virtual function print p1->print(); The pointer p1 still [points to an object of the type B.

Comment: @FrancoisAndrieux So  what does ```*p1 = p1->minus()``` really do ? How is the copy really made between ```*p1``` that is a base pointer that points to a derived and ```p->minus()``` that is a pure base object ?

Comment: @alexMcKenzie *"between `*p1` that is a base pointer"* -- no, `*p1` is an object, not a pointer. The pointer is `p1` (no `*`) and you are not assigning a new value to `p1`.

Comment: @alexMcKenzie `*p1 = p1->minus()` copy assigns (copies the value of) the value of `p1->minus()` to `*p1`. Since `minus()` returns an `A` it will just copy the `A` portion, so it just assigns `p1->x` the value of `p1->minus().x`. `p1` still points to the same, original `B` and only the `x` member was (potentially) changed by the expression.

Answer (score 4):

You created an object of the type `class B`

```
A* p1 = new B(18);
```

So the pointer `p1` will point to this object until it (the pointer) will be reassigned.

In this statement

```
*p1 = p1->minus();
```

the dynamically created object of the type `class B` was not deleted. Only its sub-object of the type `class A` was changed using the implicitly defined by the compiler copy assignment operator of the `class A` and the pointer `p1` still points to the same object of the type `class B`.

Thus in this statement

```
p1->print();
```

there is called the virtual function of the object of the type `class B` that by the way should be declared in the `class B` at least like

```
void print() override
{
    //..
}
```

Pay attention to that you should declare a virtual destructor in the class A. For example

```
virtual ~A() = default;
```

And before exiting main you should delete the dynamically allocated object.

```
delete p1;
```